# Avoid setting `.tls=true` for every route

Tags: ssl, networking, routes, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm using traefik as a reverse proxy. Clients connect to Traefik via HTTPS, but Traefik connects to the service via HTTP.

I decided to add a test service to my docker compose file:

```yaml
  test:
    image: hashicorp/http-echo
    command: -text="Hello, World!"
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.test-domain.rule=Host(`test.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.test-domain.tls=true"
```

Everything works and I can see "Hello, World!" at https://test.localhost. However, if I remove `traefik.http.routers.test-domain.tls=true` it no longer works, and traefik start returning 404 at that URL.

I can see how the `.rule` label would need to be provided for every single service, because in each case the domain would be different. But the `.tls` label would always be exactly the same, since all of my services will use TLS termination with HTTP to backend. It seems tedious to keep adding `traefik.http.routers.[ ... ].domain.tls=true` to all my services. Is there a way to have traefik just assume all services will be `.tls=true`?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Ldez](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/7768#issuecomment-761050198), this can be done by setting `tls` to `true` on the :443 entrypoint:

```
  traefik:
   # ...
    command:
     # ...
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls=true
     # ...
```